# Hide Navbar on mobile after a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, navbar

I'm building a small website and I'd like to hide the mobile navbar after a link is clicked.
I've found some similar questions in this forum: tried hide() and slideup() but it works for the very first link clicked, then I can't re-open my navbar.

The idea is to automatically close the navbar once a link is clicked to simplify and make the website more pleasant.

Here the html of my navbar:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
          <li><a class="click" href="./index.html" title="">01 : Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="click" href="#thedavid" title="">02 : The Project</a></li>
          <li><a class="click" href="#aboutus" title="">03 : About us</a></li>
          <li><a class="click" href="#roadmap" title="">04 : Our Goal</a></li>
          <li><a class="click" href="#faq" title="">05 : Faq</a></li>
        </ul>


      </div> 
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('sr-only').addEventListener('click',myFunction)

function myFunction(){
   let nav=document.getElementById('navbar-collapse')
   if(nav.style.display=="" || nav.style.display=='block')
   nav.style.display = 'none'
   else nav.style.display='block'
   }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span id="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
          <li><a class="click" href="./index.html" title="">01 : Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="click" href="#thedavid" title="">02 : The Project</a></li>
          <li><a class="click" href="#aboutus" title="">03 : About us</a></li>
          <li><a class="click" href="#roadmap" title="">04 : Our Goal</a></li>
          <li><a class="click" href="#faq" title="">05 : Faq</a></li>
        </ul>


      </div> 
    </div>
  </nav>
```